# A lot of junk values in omp while using file io

Tags: arrays, openmp

A file containing the numbers in the form of "1 2 3... and so on till 100" is being read and put into a array of size 100. The minimum element of the array is found and printed. But there are a lot of garbage values in reading the array.[Here is the output I get :C](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OKcJ5.png)

```
#pragma omp parallel for schedule(dynamic)
for (i = 1; i < MAX; i++)
{
    if(a[i]<min)
  {
   printf("%d\t",a[i]);
   min = a[i];
   loc = i+1;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't use a compiler which supports openmp4 reduction (min:
.

You will need omp critical .  As your printf implies serialization this may not slow it further.